# MySQL query to group and sort last two results based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

My table is like this. Person visits either UK or USA. I need when is the last time a person visited UK and USA. So each person only two records in desired output based on date order by desc

```
name     visited            vdate
----------------------------------------------------
A     UK (Scotland)         2020-05-12 12:00:10
B     USA (Mexico)          2020-07-23 05:14:59
A     UK (England)          2020-06-01 12:00:13
A     UK (Canada)           2020-06-18 16:20:47
B     USA (Mexico)          2020-05-05 12:54:56
C     USA (Peru)            2020-05-26 10:49:24
A     USA (Chile)           2020-06-12 07:15:18
B     UK (Northern Ireland) 2020-06-24 13:08:28
C     UK (Wales)            2020-06-22 00:43:22
C     USA (Cuba)            2020-05-22 03:37:23
B     UK (Wales)            2020-05-12 12:00:10
A     USA (Venezuela)       2020-05-14 14:41:35
C     USA (Peru)            2020-06-02 02:20:01
```

Desired Results

```
A    UK         2020-06-24 13:08:28
A    USA        2020-06-12 07:15:18
B    UK         2020-06-24 13:08:28
B    USA        2020-07-23 05:14:59 
C    UK         2020-06-22 00:43:22
C    USA        2020-06-02 02:20:01
```

I tried like this, but that gives 2 records per person, but may not be one UK and one USA

```
select * from placetbl tbl
 where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM placetbl tbl1 WHERE tbl1.name = tbl.name AND tbl1.vdate >= tbl.vdate) <= 2 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) of the date, for the Countries you ca use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE placetbl  (
>   `name` VARCHAR(1),
>   `visited` VARCHAR(41),
>   `vdate` Datetime
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO placetbl 
>   (`name`, `visited`, `vdate`)
> VALUES
>   ('A', 'UK (Scotland)', '2020-05-12 12:00:10'),
>   ('B', 'USA (Mexico)', '2020-07-23 05:14:59'),
>   ('A', 'UK (England)', '2020-06-01 12:00:13'),
>   ('A', 'UK (Canada)', '2020-06-18 16:20:47'),
>   ('B', 'USA (Mexico)', '2020-05-05 12:54:56'),
>   ('C', 'USA (Peru)', '2020-05-26 10:49:24'),
>   ('A', 'USA (Chile)', '2020-06-12 07:15:18'),
>   ('B', 'UK (Northern Ireland)','2020-06-24 13:08:28'),
>   ('C', 'UK (Wales)', '2020-06-22 00:43:22'),
>   ('C', 'USA (Cuba)', '2020-05-22 03:37:23'),
>   ('B', 'UK (Wales)', '2020-05-12 12:00:10'),
>   ('A', 'USA (Venezuela)', '2020-05-14 14:41:35'),
>   ('C', 'USA (Peru)', '2020-06-02 02:20:01');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `name`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`visited`,' ',1) visited, MAX(`vdate`) vdate 
> FROM placetbl 
> GROUP BY `name`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`visited`,' ',1)
> ORDER BY NAME, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`visited`,' ',1)
> ```
>
> ```
> name | visited | vdate              
> :--- | :------ | :------------------
> A    | UK      | 2020-06-18 16:20:47
> A    | USA     | 2020-06-12 07:15:18
> B    | UK      | 2020-06-24 13:08:28
> B    | USA     | 2020-07-23 05:14:59
> C    | UK      | 2020-06-22 00:43:22
> C    | USA     | 2020-06-02 02:20:01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d834ccc6a7c479d7dd70fde9c4a637e)*

Comment: Yeah you are right, i usedd the original column names as alias

Answer (score 2):

First get the correct country name and then group by

```
SELECT MAX(VDATE), NAME, VISITED FROM (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(visited,' ',1) VISITED, VDATE, NAME FROM TABLE1) A
GROUP BY NAME, VISITED;
```

Comment: not giving desired result, try your query in the fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d834ccc6a7c479d7dd70fde9c4a637e) made by @nbk

Comment: Just tried in fiddle and result is same.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39ab53f619f11266f109da647158d276

Comment: @Koustuv Chatterjee : How do you say it's not giving desired results ?